# SQLite query to select questions for specific quiz in DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile-application

This is just the continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207995/sqlite-database-query-for-multiple-table) thread.

I am creating an android app quiz with different topics. So i have buttons for the topics and [quizNum column in my database](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2coiu77.jpg) for Quiz1, Quiz2, Quiz3 and so on...

Here's my code for Quiz.java

```
public class Practice extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

//constants
public static final String QUIZNUM = "QUIZNUM";
public static final int Quiz1 = 1;
public static final int Quiz2 = 2;
public static final int Quiz3 = 3;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.practice);

    //Menu buttons
    Button quiz1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1Btn);
    quiz1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button quiz2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q2Btn);
    quiz2.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button quiz3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q3Btn);
    quiz3.setOnClickListener(this);

}



public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;

    List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();

    switch (v.getId()){


    case R.id.q1Btn :

        //Initialize quiz with retrieved question set
        CurrentQuiz c = new CurrentQuiz();
        c.setQuestions(questions);
        c.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
        c.setQuizNum(getQuizNum());

        ((MLearningApp)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);  


        i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;


    case R.id.q2Btn :


        CurrentQuiz c2 = new CurrentQuiz();
        c2.setQuestions(questions);
        c2.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
        c2.setQuizNum(getQuizNum());
        ((MLearningApp)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c2);  


        i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.q3Btn :

        CurrentQuiz c3 = new CurrentQuiz();
        c3.setQuestions(questions);
        c3.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
        c3.setQuizNum(getQuizNum());
        ((MLearningApp)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c3);  


        i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}


// Method that retrieves a random set of questions from db

private List<Question> getQuestionSetFromDb() throws Error {

    int quizNum = getQuizNum();
    int numQuestions = getNumQuestions();
    DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }
    List<Question> questions = myDbHelper.getQuestionSet(quizNum, numQuestions);
    myDbHelper.close();
    return questions;
}


private int getQuizNum() {
    int qNum = Quiz1;
    return qNum;    
}



private int getNumQuestions() {
    int numRounds = 10;
    return numRounds;
}
```

And here's my query in DBHelper.java

```
public List<Question> getQuestionSet(int qNum, int numQ){
    List<Question> questionSet = new ArrayList<Question>();

    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE qNum = " + qNum + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + numQ, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){

        Question q = new Question();
        q.setQuestion(c.getString(2));
        q.setAnswer(c.getString(3));
        q.setOption1(c.getString(4));
        q.setOption2(c.getString(5));

        questionSet.add(q);
    }
    return questionSet;
}
```

The quiz buttons are now running but it only retrieves questions from quiz1 (qNum table in db, 1). I was thinking of putting a looping statement in getQuizNum() method but i dont have an idea for the needed codes

Answer (score 0):

> The quiz buttons are now running but it only retrieves questions from quiz1

This is because you use `getQuizNum()` method to obtain which quiz to query:

```
private List<Question> getQuestionSetFromDb() throws Error {
    int quizNum = getQuizNum();
    //rest of the code...
}
```

And by looking at the implementation of `getQuizNum()`, you always return 1:

```
public static final int Quiz1 = 1;
//...
private int getQuizNum() {
    int qNum = Quiz1;
    return qNum;    
}
```

Change the code in `getQuizNum` to return one of the available results. Use a [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) value, for example:

```
public static final int MAX_QUIZ_QUANTITY = 3;

private int getQuizNum() {
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(MAX_QUIZ_QUANTITY) + 1;
}
```

---

I misunderstood the initial question but the problem remains the same. You should provide a different instance that implements `OnClickListener` interface for your quiz buttons. An alternative would be to move the code to implement `onClick` method into an inner class, thus removing the repeated code and making it reusable for different buttons:

```
//removed the implementation of OnClickListener from the class
//and moved into an inner class
//usually, your Activity doesn't implement OnClickListener unless there's a single button
public class Practice extends Activity {

    //constants
    public static final String QUIZNUM = "QUIZNUM";
    public static final int Quiz1 = 1;
    public static final int Quiz2 = 2;
    public static final int Quiz3 = 3;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 10;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.practice);

        //Menu buttons
        Button quiz1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1Btn);
        quiz1.setOnClickListener(new PracticeButton(Quiz1, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS));

        Button quiz2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q2Btn);
        quiz2.setOnClickListener(new PracticeButton(Quiz2, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS));

        Button quiz3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q3Btn);
        quiz3.setOnClickListener(new PracticeButton(Quiz3, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS));
    }

    //inner class that provides the common functionality for the buttons
    class PracticeButton implements OnClickListener {

        //declaring fields in the inner class to provide flexibility
        //think of them as the necessary external parameters
        //for the functionality of the button
        int quizNumber;
        int numQuestions;
        //stating that the consumer of this class must provide the
        //parameters for the functionality of the button
        public PracticeButton(int quizNum, int numQuestions) {
            this.quizNum = quizNum;
            this.numQuestions = numQuestions;
        }

        //here you implement the onClick
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //the switch is not necessary anymore
            Intent i;
            List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();
            CurrentQuiz c = new CurrentQuiz();
            c.setQuestions(questions);
            c.setNumRounds(numQuestions);
            c.setQuizNum(quizNum);
            ((MLearningApp)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);  
            i = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        //replaced Error by Exception
        //Error should not be used, leave it to the JVM
        private List<Question> getQuestionSetFromDb() throws Exception {
            //moved these variables as fields
            //int quizNum = this.quizNumber;
            //int numQuestions = getNumQuestions();
            DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(QuestionActivity.this);
            try {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to create database");
            }
            try {
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }
            List<Question> questions = myDbHelper.getQuestionSet(quizNum, numQuestions);
            myDbHelper.close();
            return questions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it randomizes quiz questions in different quizzes. It doesnt fit (qNum) 1 = Quiz1 button, (qNum) 2 = Quiz2 button, (qNum) 3 = Quiz3 button, what happens is that when i click quiz1 button, sometimes questions from quiz3 shows. When i click quiz2 btn, questions from q1 shows. It is because of the random right? but how would it get right?

Comment: @KaitlinReyes answer updated with another approach to solve the problem.

Comment: @KaitlinReyes sorry, my bad. Code fixed.

Comment: It gives an error in QuestionActivity.this ( both in the intent and DBHelper) which says "no enclosing instance of type is accessible in scope"

Comment: @KaitlinReyes now that's strange. I just tested the code and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show the relevant parts of the code:

```
switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.q1Btn :
    c.setQuizNum(getQuizNum());
    break;
case R.id.q2Btn :
    c2.setQuizNum(getQuizNum());
    break;
case R.id.q3Btn :
    c3.setQuizNum(getQuizNum());
    break;
}
```

`getQuizNum()` is useless; you want to set the actual number instead:

```
switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.q1Btn :
    c.setQuizNum(1);
    break;
case R.id.q2Btn :
    c2.setQuizNum(2);
    break;
case R.id.q3Btn :
    c3.setQuizNum(3);
    break;
}
```

Comment: How would i set it from there?